# Ansible Automate configuration by iterating over files and assigning variables for each host

Tags: ansible, yaml, jinja2

I need some help here in determining the best way to do this and how to setup my playbook to appropriately pull variables for each node.

Lets say I have 3 hosts

```
/etc/ansible/hosts:

host1
host2
host3
```

I have a variable file with multiple entries in it

```
vars/IPs.yaml:

---
IP: ['192.168.77.35', '192.167.77.36', '192.168.77.37']
```

I am running this playbook:

```
network_change.yaml:

---
- hosts: all
  vars_files:
    - vars/IPs.yaml
  tasks:
    - name: Check 10G Interface
      stat:
        path: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-card-10Gb-1
      register: teng

    - name: Change 10G Interface Settings
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-card-10Gb-1
        regexp: '{{item.From}}'
        line: '{{item.To}}'
      when: teng.stat.exists
      with_items:
       - { From: 'IPADDR=', To: 'IPADDR={{IP}}'}
```

I have this working for a single host just fine...but when I have multiple hosts I'm not sure how to loop through the IPs.yaml variables and pull the next value the next time the loop runs.  Is there also a way for me to not use a dictionary .yaml variable, can I just use a raw text file that has the IPs on newlines?

Essentially I want to loop through and have the hosts show this in each of the respective hosts /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-card-10Gb-1.

host1 = 'IPADDR=192.168.77.35'

host2 = 'IPADDR=192.168.77.36'

host3 = 'IPADDR=192.168.77.37'

The end game is to be able to do this over 100+ hosts with simple text files, rather than dictionary yaml files and will be including multiple variables, etc.  The systems will all be able to be hit via dhcp/hostnames/IP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a dictionary with the data, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        _dict: '{{ dict(ansible_play_hosts|zip(IP)) }}'
      run_once: true
```

should give

```yaml
  _dict:
    host1: 192.168.77.35
    host2: 192.167.77.36
    host3: 192.168.77.37
```

Then use this dictionary and select the IP, e.g.

```yaml
    - name: Change 10G Interface Settings
      lineinfile:
        path: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-card-10Gb-1
        regexp: 'IPADDR='
        line: 'IPADDR={{ _dict[inventory_hostname] }}'
      when: teng.stat.exists
```

You might want to test it first, e.g.

```yaml
    - name: Change 10G Interface Settings
      debug:
        msg: 'IPADDR={{ _dict[inventory_hostname] }}'
```

should give

```yaml
ok: [host2] => 
  msg: IPADDR=192.167.77.36
ok: [host1] => 
  msg: IPADDR=192.168.77.35
ok: [host3] => 
  msg: IPADDR=192.168.77.37
```

---

The next option, instead of creating the dictionary, is to calculate the index in the list, e.g. should give the same result

```yaml
    - name: Change 10G Interface Settings
      debug:
        msg: 'IPADDR={{ IP[_index|int] }}'
      vars:
        _index: '{{ ansible_play_hosts.index(inventory_hostname) }}'
```

---

Q: *"**Use a raw text file that has the IPs on newlines**"*

A: Create the file, e.g.

```sh
shell> cat IP.txt 
192.168.77.35
192.167.77.36
192.168.77.37
```

Create the list on the fly, e.g.

```yaml
    - set_fact:
        IP: "{{ lookup('file', 'IP.txt').split('\n') }}"
      run_once: true
```

should give

```yaml
  IP:
  - 192.168.77.35
  - 192.167.77.36
  - 192.168.77.37
```

---

The more robust solution would be to put the hashes into the file, e.g.

```sh
shell> cat IP.txt
host1: 192.168.77.35
host2: 192.167.77.36
host3: 192.168.77.37
```

Then the task

```yaml
    - include_vars:
        file: IP.txt
        name: _dict
```

should create the dictionary

```yaml
  _dict:
    host1: 192.168.77.35
    host2: 192.167.77.36
    host3: 192.168.77.37
```

---

But, the most simple solution would be to store this dictionary in IP.yml and put it into the directory *group_vars/all*.

Comment: Wow, very detailed and explains a lot!! Thank you so much Vladmir.  My only question is on the raw text file (IP.txt) example how can the file be iterated through in the lineinfile loop?  The other examples use the invetory hostname...i'm just failing to find a way to have each host pull the next newline rather than the first entry in the raw text file...

Comment: You're welcome. The result of ``each host pulls the next newline`` is the dictionary, isn't it? I don't understand what you mean by ``iterate the file in the lineinfile loop``. What is the expected result? If you have a problem [edit] question (or open a new one) and make it [mre].

Comment: I think I found what I needed in your comment where you mention:
`The next option, instead of creating the dictionary, is to calculate the index in the list, e.g. should give the same result`

Comment: I see. Use it if you're sure the items and order of *ansible_play_hosts* are correct.